# Turning multiple database queries into one

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a list of 10 match_id:region pairs and

currently what I'm doing is calling this individual query 10 times for each pair.

```
SELECT uuid, url, score
FROM vods 
  JOIN match ON vods.id = match.vod
  JOIN users ON match.owner = users.id
WHERE match_id = $1 
  AND match.region = $2 
  AND users.region = $2
```

The result of those 10 queries are then added to a JSON object.

```
{
  uuid0: {
    url: "",
    score: "",
  },
  ...
}
```

I was wondering if there was a way to achieve the same with a single query rather than multiple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an IN condition with tuples

```
SELECT uuid, url, score
FROM vods 
  JOIN match ON vods.id = match.vod
  JOIN users ON match.owner = users.id AND match.region = users.region
WHERE (match_id, match.region) in ( (1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4), ...)
```